# Is there an efficient way to format Decimal?

Tags: python, performance, archlinux, f-string, python-decimal

It is nice, easy and fast to use format-strings in python. So I never considered the performance penalty of this operation. Some time ago I switched my program from `float` data type to `Decimal` to eliminate rounding errors. Some performance degradation was expected and it is ok. But I'm surprised to see how large performance penalty I have just from printing a log of formatted `Decimal` numbers.

Below I illustrate the difference with *cProfile* results.
The question is - are there any efficient ways to have formatted `Decimal` numbers in python?

Here is a test for float-number formatting:

```
from cProfile import Profile

a_float = 1234567890.12345

def format_float(value: float) -> str:
    if value is None:
        return ''
    result = f"{value:+,.6f}"
    return result

def test_float():
    for i in range(1000000):
        b = format_float(a_float)

p = Profile()
p.runcall(test_float)
p.print_stats()
```

it gives result: 1000002 function calls in **0.839 seconds**

And here is the same test with *Decimal*:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from cProfile import Profile

a_decimal = Decimal('1234567890.12345')

def format_decimal(value: Decimal) -> str:
    if value is None:
        return ''
    result = f"{value:+,.6f}"
    return result

def test_decimal():
    for i in range(1000000):
        b = format_decimal(a_decimal)

p = Profile()
p.runcall(test_decimal)
p.print_stats()
```

which results in: 55000002 function calls in **27.739 seconds**

Is there any way to format `Decimal` nicely in shorter time?

The discussion in comments brought nice spot - that others don't have such a problem. Here I think the output of the profiler is of some interest.

For the case with `float` it is pretty short and ends with `{method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}` that suggest some optimization I think:

```
>>> p.print_stats()
         1000002 function calls in 0.735 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    0.564    0.000    0.564    0.000 <stdin>:1(format_float)
        1    0.171    0.171    0.735    0.735 <stdin>:1(test_float)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

while with `Decimal` there are a lot of lines:

```
>>> p.print_stats()
         47000029 function calls in 23.731 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1000000    0.625    0.000   23.395    0.000 <stdin>:1(format_decimal)
        1    0.335    0.335   23.731   23.731 <stdin>:1(test_decimal)
  1000000    0.947    0.000    1.795    0.000 _pydecimal.py:2622(_rescale)
  1000000    3.218    0.000   22.771    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3758(__format__)
  1000000    0.533    0.000    0.665    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3844(_dec_from_triple)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3902(__init__)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3938(_set_integer_check)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3952(_set_signal_dict)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _pydecimal.py:3963(__setattr__)
  1000000    0.294    0.000    0.405    0.000 _pydecimal.py:448(getcontext)
  1000000    1.974    0.000    3.767    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6188(_parse_format_specifier)
  1000000    0.870    0.000    0.988    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6268(_format_align)
  1000000    1.734    0.000    1.822    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6295(_group_lengths)
  1000000    6.271    0.000   10.549    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6318(_insert_thousands_sep)
  1000000    0.236    0.000    0.236    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6355(_format_sign)
  1000000    1.390    0.000   13.162    0.000 _pydecimal.py:6365(_format_number)
  3000000    0.466    0.000    0.466    0.000 _pydecimal.py:820(__bool__)
  1000000    0.132    0.000    0.132    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x7e4f98d56d40}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
 16000000    0.979    0.000    0.979    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  4000000    0.732    0.000    0.732    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
  4000000    0.524    0.000    0.524    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fromkeys}
  4000000    0.277    0.000    0.277    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1000000    0.112    0.000    0.112    0.000 {method 'get' of '_contextvars.ContextVar' objects}
  1000000    0.613    0.000    0.613    0.000 {method 'groupdict' of 're.Match' objects}
  1000000    0.289    0.000    0.289    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  1000000    1.180    0.000    1.180    0.000 {method 'match' of 're.Pattern' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'set' of '_contextvars.ContextVar' objects}
```

In fast test ran by *Suramuthu R* here [here](https://imgur.com/Y6PRJEC) I see that his `Decimal` test is similar to my `float` and ends with the line:

```
{method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

It looks like some optimization is switched off for `Decimal` on my PC.
Does anyone have idea how to check it?

Comment: Where/how are you running these tests? I'm getting `1000002 function calls in 1.049 seconds` for floats and `1000002 function calls in 1.126 seconds` for Decimal on Python 3.8

Comment: Hi DeepSpace. Initially I ran in PyCharm and Jupyter just due to convenient GUI. After your comment I ran in console just like command "python test.py" - it gave me sligthly better result (19 seconds VS 0.7 seconds) but still quite slow. I run Arch Linux with Python 3.11.6. Maybe it is about how Decimal is installed?.. but I don't see any specific packet for it... Which OS do you use with such great results?

Comment: In python 3.10.12, this is the result. for float : 1000002 function calls in 0.637 seconds;

for decimal :1000002 function calls in 0.419 seconds; [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/Y6PRJEC). In online-compiler, it takes more time. Even then, for decimal, it takes lesser time. My suggestion is to get your python version updated to 3 and above and to test the result in terminal.

Comment: Ok, guys, Thank you,  you give me hope... But... may you give more details about your setups? It appears I need to dig dipper and do more experiments but I need some direction. (I'll try with lower python version later today)

Comment: So your own measurements are 0.839s / 1000002 = 838ns for float and 27.739s / 55000002 = 504ns for decimal. Decimal is faster. What's the issue?

Comment: I ran in pure python console as @Suramuthu R did. The result is still the same for me, but I spotted one difference - on his screenshot the last call is `{method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}`. I have the same for `float` but longer list for `Decimal`. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: Yuri, the issue is that 550000002 is an interal calls counter. I do test with the same 10e6 number if iterations.

Comment: Yuri, no, this isn't true. It shows that `test_decimal` has much more calls under the hood comparing to `test_float`. Yes, it looks to be a reason of the problem, but I don't think that profiler calls it more. I think it is some overhead inside, related with debug optimizations of something (I think so due to this line `{method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}`)

Comment: You are right, the issue is that your setup is using pure-python implementation of decimal for some reason (you can see `_pydecimal.py` in the statistics) whereas it should be using C implementation. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/decimal.py).

Comment: I suspect yuri  is right, in my case, Arch Linux (vanilla) on a SteamDeck: 


Using Python 3.12.1 (installed with PyEnv) my results are similar to those shown by others in the comments:


`1000002 function calls in 1.586 seconds` for float and `1000002 function calls in 1.271 seconds` for Decimal.

Using the version of Python supplied with Arch (pacman) : `47000029 function calls in 23.697 seconds` for Decimal and the output of the profiles similar to the one you show in the question.

Comment: Ok, I did another test with `timeit` instead of `cProfile` - results are on screenshot https://ibb.co/HgTzygm - 0.54 vs 7.26 seconds. The ratio is better but `Decimal` is still slower. Last, I did the same test without profiler at all and with simple stopwatch - `Decimal` is much slower. So I still think it isn't someting that profiler does wrong. It rather something inside Python as FJSevilla shown the same result on Arch as mine with pacman package. It feels like I need to address it towards arch package mainteiners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in the version of Python provided by the Arch repositories because  it forces the use of several libraries installed on the system when compiling Python ([see Python PKGBUILD](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/python/-/blob/main/PKGBUILD?ref_type=heads#L40)), among them libmpdec.

So, the cause is the lack of the optional `mpdecimal` dependency, whose absence forces Python to use the Python implementation of Decimal, as [yuri kilochek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554020/yuri-kilochek) correctly pointed out in the comments:

> ... the problem is that your configuration is using a pure python decimal
> implementation for some reason (you can see _pydecimal.py in the
> stats) while it should be using a C implementation.

[image]

Installing the [mpdecimal](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/mpdecimal/) package fixes the problem:

```
sudo pacman -S install mpdecimal
```

[image]

Being faster than for the `float` case, `1000002 function calls in 1.104 seconds` in this same system.

Comment: Great! You are right, `mpdecimal` was not installed and it solved my problem in a moment. Thanks a lot to all who contributed!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour appears to differ significantly depending on platform.

For example, on MacOS 14.3.1 and Python 3.12.1 on Apple Silicon M2 this code:

```
from cProfile import Profile
from decimal import Decimal


def format_float(value) -> str:
    return f"{value:+,.6f}"

def test_value():
    global a_x
    for _ in range(1_000_000):
        format_float(a_x)

v = 1234567890.12345

for a_x in Decimal(v), v:
    p = Profile()
    p.runcall(test_value)
    p.print_stats()
```

...produces this output...

```
         1000002 function calls in 0.304 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.075    0.075    0.304    0.304 Feb11.py:10(test_value)
  1000000    0.229    0.000    0.229    0.000 Feb11.py:7(format_float)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


         1000002 function calls in 0.449 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.077    0.077    0.449    0.449 Feb11.py:10(test_value)
  1000000    0.372    0.000    0.372    0.000 Feb11.py:7(format_float)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

...where we see far fewer calls being made than shown in the OP. Why formatting of Decimal is (apparently) faster than float is a mystery to me

Comment: Yes, as FJSevilla correctly found - my platform missed essential C-implementation package. I think it is logical that `Decimal` is faster. I mean `float` is a pure binary format while `Decimal` is stored in some more human-readable format to keep all these digits as I understand. So there seems to be less binary to human converstion steps involved.